# Given a $P$ does this always imply either $Q$ or $\neg Q$? (not both at the same time)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given a $P$ does this always imply either $Q$ or $\neg Q$?
I want to show that given a $P$, then either $Q$ holds or $\neg Q$ holds (that is, not both at the same time).
My attempted proof is the following: since $P$ is given, then this implies that it is "true", then one could say that $P$ implies $Q$ or $\neg Q$, but these last two cases are exclusive , then $P$ implies only one of them and not both.

If that proof is valid, then it seems strange to me, since it is not necessary that $Q$ (or $\neg Q$) can be logically deduced from $P$, as an example: "If it rains tomorrow, then I either study or I don't study", the proposition is true, although I cannot deduce that actually raining implies that I study or not.

Edited:

I think it can get much weirder, for example if $P$ implies $Q$ or $\neg Q$, and $\neg Q$ implies $R$. Then $P$ implies $Q$ or $R$.

I have written this, assuming that the above written before editing this message is correct.

Comment: Two tips: 1) $p\to(q\vee\neg q)$ means that if $p$ then $q\vee \neg q $, even if you don't know whether $q$ or $\neg q$. 2) 'implies' doen't mean 'is because', that is, the logical implication does not involve any causality. $p\to (q\vee \neg q)$ means only that $p$ is false or $q\vee\neg q$ is true.

For example, 'cats have six legs implies that the sun sets at West', is logically true.

Comment: A logical implication need not entail causation.

Comment: I just realized your question is unclear … in my Answer below I took your question to be:  ‘How can “if it rains, then I either study or not” be true, even though neither “if it rains, then I study” nor “if it rains, then I don’t study” is true?’.  But now I am not so sure that that is what your question is … can you please clarify? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful separating between the various ways in which we use ‘implies’.

If by ‘implies’ you mean ‘logically implies’, then please note that $P$ does indeed logically imply $Q \lor \neg Q$, but this does not mean that either $P$ logically implies $Q$ or that $P$ logically implies $\neg Q$. Indeed, we can use your very example as a counterexample.

If by ‘implies’ you mean the truth-functional operator or connective known as the material implication, then it *is* true that for any $P$ and $Q$ at least one of $P \to Q$ or $P \to \neg Q$ is true. But that is only weird *if* you treat the material implication as something more than it is. Indeed, if you treat it as a natural language conditional (‘if … then ...’). you will often get counterintuitive results, known as the Paradoxes of the Material Implication.

Comment: I have tried to be clear, but I don't speak English very well, I'm sorry.
Well, actually, as you mention, I must separate the meaning of the word $implies$ from a mathematical language to everyday use, for example. Anyway, my initial question was because I saw a proof of Zorn's lemma where given a $P$ this implies a $Q$ or $\neg Q$, but at the same time $\neg Q$ implies a $R$, so it follows that given a $P$, then either $Q$ or $R$. That seemed very strange to me, I understand that it is logically correct, but I have a hard time assimilating it.

Answer (score 0):

Implication does not imply causation. It merely implies that *if* the antecedent is true, *then* the consequent will also be true. In other words, the implicaiton states that the consequent is true whenever the antecedent is true. For instance, consider the statement

"*if* a person is pregnant, *then* that person has a uterus"

The above implication is obviously true, and we know that being pregnant does not cause one to have a uterus. You may find it helpful to understand the implication in terms of set theory. The above implication conveys that the set of instances in which a person is pregnant is a subset of the set of instances in which that person has a uterus. For this reason, if we are presented with an instance of a person being pregnant, then we must also have an instance in which that person has a uterus. There are numerous relationships like this that exist, and not all imply causation between the antecedent and consequent.

With that being said, lets take a closer look at your statement

"*if* it rains tomorrow, *then* either I study or I don't study"

The set of instances in which you either study or don't study is in fact the set off all possible instances. The set of instances in which rains tomorrow is a subset of this set. Hence, if tomorrow is an instance in which it rains, then tomorrow must be instance in which you either study or don't study.

**In addition, I hesitate to call your proof valid** because saying "*then one could say that $P$ implies $Q$ or $\neg Q$*" does not exactly prove $P \to (Q \vee \neg Q)$ on the basis of $P$ alone. The chain of reasoning you're using is obscure.

I think a poof of $P \to (Q \vee \neg Q)$ would be better stated as follows: Assume $P$ is true. Now consider that either $Q$ or $\neg Q$ is true. So, under the assumption that $P$ is true, we have shown that either $Q$ or $\neg Q$ is true. Thus, if $P$ is true, then either $Q$ or $\neg Q$ is true.

Comment: "Implication does not imply causation'  haha.